# Malicious ip/website blocked on a legitimate program

Tags: anti-malware

I'm fairly okay with PCs but when it comes to networking I'm quite lost with the details.

My brother started up mount and blade war band napoleonic wars - an official game and played multiplayer and joined a server.

malwarebytes started blocking outbound connections to 176.53.17.226 on ports 49287, 63932, 65135, 57512 and 60600.

It showed mountblade warband_/mb_warband.exe being blocked.

Is my PC in danger? Is it a false positive?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Internet. Garbage and background noise are common. You can investigate every minor incident if you want, but you'll probably never get to do anything else with your life. If you don't have some specific reason to be concerned, I'd just suggest forgetting about it.

Comment: Its just Ive never come up with a false positive before, but I never played that particular game with mbam on. I was worried with the network part of it incase it had something to do with keylogging

Comment: It's probably not quite a false positive. There probably is something malicious at that site, though most likely not the thing that you were accessing.

Comment: What do you mean by that? It is a legitimate program from steam but I wanted to be sure. What I meant by saying id never had a false positive was because I never ran any games when I had malwarebytes. Im confused about your answer now, you said forgetting about it first and now saying its probably not false?

Comment: @Keyes That's correct. I'm saying forget about it but that it's probably not false. Do you really want to spend the rest of your life running down every possible malicious thing your computer might ever encounter? Many legitimate programs can be induced to transfer malware -- your browser is, I hope, a legitimate program. But it can certainly be made to transfer malware.

Comment: Okay, but what did you mean exactly by "It's probably not quite a false positive. There probably is something malicious at that site, "

Comment: Im not sure whether youre saying it ia malicious or not.

Comment: @Keyes There probably is (or was) something malicious at the site you are trying to access that caused malwarebytes to list it. It could be as small as an advertisement that has embedded malware. Many legitimate programs can be induced to transfer malware -- for example, your browser.